# Data in row in Gridview not updating to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

When I click on the edit button next a given row in my `GridView` and edit the field and select update nothing happens.  It just returns to the `GridView` with no changes made to that specific row.

This is the code I am using:

```
protected void OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    int customerId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
    string name = (row.FindControl("txtName") as TextBox).Text;
    string email = (row.FindControl("txtEmail") as TextBox).Text;
    string license = (row.FindControl("txtLicense") as TextBox).Text;
    string query = "UPDATE License SET Name=@DisplayName, EmailAddress=@EmailAddress, LicenseType=@LicenseType WHERE CustomerId=@CustomerId";
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", customerId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayName", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseType", license);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    this.BindGrid();
}
```

And :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                      <ContentTemplate>
                          <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="mydatagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"
                              DataKeyNames="CustomerId" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit" PageSize="3"
                              OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" EmptyDataText="No records has been added."
                              Width="348px" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" AllowSorting="true">
                              <Columns>
                                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Display Name" ItemStyle-Width="100">
                                      <ItemTemplate>
                                          <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                      </ItemTemplate>
                                      <EditItemTemplate>
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' Width="250"></asp:TextBox>
                                      </EditItemTemplate>
                                      <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                                  </asp:TemplateField>
                                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email Address" ItemStyle-Width="100">
                                      <ItemTemplate>
                                          <asp:Label ID="lblEmailAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
                                      </ItemTemplate>
                                      <EditItemTemplate>
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailAddress") %>' Width="250"></asp:TextBox>
                                      </EditItemTemplate>
                                      <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                                  </asp:TemplateField>
                                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="License Type" ControlStyle-Width="100px">
                                      <ItemTemplate>
                                          <asp:Label ID="lblLicense" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LicenseType") %>'></asp:Label>
                                      </ItemTemplate>
                                      <EditItemTemplate>
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtLicense" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LicenseType") %>' Width="140"></asp:TextBox>
                                      </EditItemTemplate>
                                       <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                                  </asp:TemplateField>
                                  <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-success" ShowEditButton="true" ControlStyle-Width="100px" ControlStyle-ForeColor="Black" ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                                       ItemStyle-Width="200" >
                                  <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-success" />
                                  <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                                  </asp:CommandField>
                                  <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-danger" ShowDeleteButton="true" ControlStyle-Width="100px" ControlStyle-ForeColor="Black" ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                                      ItemStyle-Width="200" >
                                  <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-danger" />
                                  <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                                  </asp:CommandField>
                              </Columns>
                              <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                              <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" width="250px" />
                              <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                              <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                              <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                              <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
                              <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
                              <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
                              <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
                          </asp:GridView><br /><br />
```

I can delete the row and add another row, but not edit it?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the field, the data in db is update ?

Personally, I have a function to refresh the `GreadView` each time I do an edit :

```
public void RefreshGridView()
{
    List<myClass> result = getAllElementsClassFunction();
    grdUser.DataSource = result;
    grdUser.DataBind();
}
```

Put this function at the end of your `OnRowUpdating` :

```
protected void OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    ...

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    RefreshGridView();
}
```